# Cannot configure sources

Tags: linux

I got in trouble with installing app from source code. From console I started configure script, fixed some missing packages but when I got

configure: WARNING: freetype2 development libraries not present (Debian package is libfreetype6-dev)

I executed command

sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev

but I still got the same error. What wrong? I use Linux 15.04

Comment: No you don't, Linux just arrived at major version number 4.

Answer (score 0):

A `configure` script is a strong indication that `GNU autotools` are used. In that case, you will find what went wrong in the **(huge)** `config.log` file. Look near the end (several pages up from it because the end is cluttered with not so helpful general output about this run of the script).

The autotools are complicated (some would say, a mess) and it's easy to get something subtlety wrong, so my guess would be the check for `freetype2` somehow fails to detect it the way the package installed on your system. If you find the source of the problem, you *could* hack the configure script (attention: **huge** again, it's auto-generated) to make it work. Sometimes it's enough to pass `configure` some `CFLAGS` making the compiler look for include files in the correct locations (e.g. `CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/freetype2' ./configure`  -- don't take this verbatim, analyze `config.log` and compare with `dpkg -L libfreetype6-dev`)